# Using parameters defined in other functions

Tags: python

I am not an expert of defining function but I would need to create a new one.

I have one function

- where I enter manually a query;
- where I set parameters like language and country;
- then the last function where I should pass all these parameters as fields.

Since the functions that I am using are too big to be reported here, I will give you an example:

```
def fun1():
   query=input("Enter query:")
   return (query)

def fun2():
   country=input("Enter country:")
   language=input("Enter language:")
   return(country, language)

def fun3():
    
     fun1()
     fun2()
     print("Country: You have selected ",country)
     print("Language: You have selected ", language)
     print("Query: You have selected ", query)
```

This does not recognise country, language and query from the previous functions.
Can you explain me how to correctly define the last functions in order to use the parameters previously set?

Comment: use `query = func1()` and `country, language = fun2()`

Comment: You need to store the result of the function calls. Like `query = fun1()`, `country, language = fun2()`

Comment: Thank you to both

Comment: BTW: `return` doesn't need `()`. You can do `return query` and `return country, language`

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you furas. It will be extremely useful!

Comment: Whatever you do, please stay away from `global` for your use-case.

Comment: @Felipe could you please explain me why? (I am a still a beginner with a lot of questions :)

Comment: Check out this post on [why global variables are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/1305461).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the functions they set `query`, `country`, and `language` within their own scopes.  The `query` is owned by `fun1()`, and `country` and `language` are owned by `fun2()`.

When these functions are done running, `query`, `country`, and `language` go out of scope and are no longer valid.

Since you are returning the values of these variables, `fun3()` should capture the results.

The correct way to do what you are trying is:

```
def fun3():
     query = fun1()
     country, language = fun2()
     print("Country: You have selected ",country)
     print("Language: You have selected ", language)
     print("Query: You have selected ", query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
def fun1():
    query = input("Enter query: ")
    return query

def fun2():
    country = input("Enter country: ")
    language = input("Enter language: ")
    return country, language

def fun3():
    
    query, (country, language) = fun1(), fun2()
    print("Country: You have selected", country)
    print("Language: You have selected", language)
    print("Query: You have selected", query)
    
fun3()
```

Input:

```
Enter query: Are you happy?
Enter country: Australia
Enter language: English
```

Output:

```
Country: You have selected Australia
Language: You have selected English
Query: You have selected Are you happy?
```